# How to get associated product Id's from grouped product Id?

Tags: magento2, grouped-products, child

I try many solutions but i can't get the result please help me for getting associated products from grouped productId like for configurable product we use

```
$parent_pro = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); 
$_children = $parent_pro->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($parent_pro)
```

**How can I get Grouped child products?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Try this**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$parent_pro = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); 
$_children = $parent_pro->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($parent_pro);
foreach ($_children as $child) {
       if ($child->getId() != $parent_pro->getId()) {
        echo "child Id ".$child->getID();
      }
}
```